# Lotus Domino 9.0.1, Create weekly recurrence meeting for all days from REST calendar service is creating differently from Lotus Notes Client

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Lotus Domino 9.0.1, create weekly recurrence meeting for all days from REST calendar service call is creating differently from Lotus Notes Client

Please try below scenario:

Create a weekly recurrence meeting which repeats every 2 weeks or every other week, on all days starting from thursday (08/13/2015 05:00PM) and select until end date (08/26/2015) as next to next week wednesday

- Lotus Notes Creates meetings on below dates:

08/13/2015 05:00PM

08/14/2015 05:00PM

08/15/2015 05:00PM

08/16/2015 05:00PM

08/17/2015 05:00PM

08/18/2015 05:00PM

08/19/2015 05:00PM

- Lotus Domino REST Calendar service:

The meeting is only created from thursday till saturday

recurrenceRule:  "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;UNTIL=20150826T173000Z;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"

08/13/2015 05:00PM

08/14/2015 05:00PM

08/15/2015 05:00PM

Kindly help me regarding this